# Downloading file with a href tag makes the file illegible

Tags: vue.js

I have the following code

```html
<a href="../../assets/all-work/proto/pdf-test.pdf" download>Download</a>
```

It's inside a vue component which is located in `src/components/Home/Proto.vue` and the file is located in `src/assets/all-work/proto/pdf-test.pdf`, when I click download it downloads something completely illegible, why's that and how could I fix it?

Comment: The urls will be relative to the nodes baseURI, which will probably be the one of your Document, usually itself set to the current location, but not of where your code-source is fetched from.

Comment: what would be the correct way to write it? I'm very confused, I use the same path for images and it works perfectly

Comment: Hmmm yeah I also get 'Failed - No file' when I try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using Vue CLI.

The default configuration generated by the Vue CLI has special handling for images. To get the same thing working for PDFs you need to configure it yourself.

Firstly, you'll need to explicitly use `require` on your `href`:

```html
<a :href="require('../../assets/all-work/proto/pdf-test.pdf')" download>Download</a>
```

In some scenarios, such as the `src` attribute of an `<img>`, the wrapping with `require` is performed automatically. For an `<a href>` it isn't.

You'll then run into a Webpack loader error because Webpack has no idea what to do with a `.pdf` file.

To fix that you'll need to configure a `file-loader` in `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack (config) {
    config.module.rule('pdf')
      .test(/\.pdf$/)
      .use('file-loader')
      .loader('file-loader')
  }
}
```

If you don't already have a `vue.config.js` file then you'll need to create one. It goes at the top level, next to your `package.json`.

If you do already have a `vue.config.js` then you'll need to merge the `chainWebpack` property in, alongside your existing configuration.

By default the file will be renamed to a hash based on its content. It you want to retain the original file name you can configure that instead:

```js
chainWebpack (config) {
  config.module.rule('pdf')
    .test(/\.pdf$/)
    .use('file-loader')
    .loader('file-loader')
    .options({
      name: '[name].[ext]'
    })
}
```

More details on the `name` option can be found at:

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/#name